# How to setup a firebase firestore and cloud function test suit with firebase Emulator for JS development

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

According to the following google I/O (2019) post of the firebase team the new emulator allows us to combine firebase/database plus cloud function to fully simulate our firebase server codes. That should also mean we should be able to write tests for it.

> we’re releasing a brand new Cloud Functions emulator that can also
>   communicate with the Cloud Firestore emulator. So if you want to build
>   a function that triggers upon a Firestore document update and writes
>   data back to the database you can code and test that entire flow
>   locally on your laptop (Source: [Firebase Blog Entry](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/05/whats-new-Google-IO-2019.html))

I could find multiple resources looking/describing each individual simulation, but no all together

1. [Unit Testing Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing)
2. [Emulate Database writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/test-rules-emulator)
3. [Emulate Firestore writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To setup a test environment for cloud functions that allows you to simulate read/write and setup test data you have to do the following. Keep in mind, this really simulated/triggers cloud functions. So after you write into firestore, you need to wait a bit until the cloud function is done writing/processing, before you can read the assert the data.

An example repo with the code below can be found here: https://github.com/BrandiATMuhkuh/jaipuna-42-firebase-emulator .

### Preconditions

I assume at this point you have a firebase project set up, with a functions folder and `index.js` in it. The tests will later be inside the `functions/test` folder. If you don't have project setup use `firebase init` to setup a project.

### Install Dependencies

First add/install the following dependencies: `mocha`, `@firebase/rules-unit-testing`, `firebase-functions-test`, `firebase-functions`, `firebase-admin`, `firebase-tools` into the `functions/package.json` NOT the root folder.

```
cd "YOUR-LOCAL-EMULATOR"/functions (for example cd C:\Users\User\Documents\FirebaseLocal\functions)

npm install --save-dev mocha
npm install --save-dev firebase-functions-test
npm install --save-dev @firebase/rules-unit-testing
npm install firebase-admin
npm install firebase-tools
```

### Replace all `jaipuna-42-firebase-emulator` names

It's very important that you use your own `project-id`. It must be the  `project-id` of your own project and must exists. Fake ids won't work. So search for all `jaipuna-42-firebase-emulator` in the code below and replace it with your `project-id`.

### index.js for an example cloud function

```js
// functions/index.js

const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

// init the database
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
let fsDB = admin.firestore();

const heartOfGoldRef = admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("spaceShip")
    .doc("Heart-of-Gold");

exports.addCrewMemeber = functions.firestore.document("characters/{characterId}").onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    console.log("characters", snap.id);

    // before doing anything we need to make sure no other cloud function worked on the assignment already
    // don't forget, cloud functions promise an "at least once" approache. So it could be multiple
    // cloud functions work on it. (FYI: this is called "idempotent")

    return fsDB.runTransaction(async t => {
        // Let's load the current character and the ship
        const [characterSnap, shipSnap] = await t.getAll(snap.ref, heartOfGoldRef);

        // Let's get the data
        const character = characterSnap.data();
        const ship = shipSnap.data();

        // set the crew members and count
        ship.crew = [...ship.crew, context.params.characterId];
        ship.crewCount = ship.crewCount + 1;

        // update character space status
        character.inSpace = true;

        // let's save to the DB
        await Promise.all([t.set(snap.ref, character), t.set(heartOfGoldRef, ship)]);
    });
});
```

### mocha test file index.test.js

```js
// functions/test/index.test.js


// START with: yarn firebase emulators:exec "yarn test --exit"
// important, project ID must be the same as we currently test

// At the top of test/index.test.js
require("firebase-functions-test")();

const assert = require("assert");
const firebase = require("@firebase/testing");

// must be the same as the project ID of the current firebase project.
// I belive this is mostly because the AUTH system still has to connect to firebase (googles servers)
const projectId = "jaipuna-42-firebase-emulator";
const admin = firebase.initializeAdminApp({ projectId });

beforeEach(async function() {
    this.timeout(0);
    await firebase.clearFirestoreData({ projectId });
});

async function snooz(time = 3000) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(e => {
            resolve();
        }, time);
    });
}

it("Add Crew Members", async function() {
    this.timeout(0);

    const heartOfGold = admin
        .firestore()
        .collection("spaceShip")
        .doc("Heart-of-Gold");

    const trillianRef = admin
        .firestore()
        .collection("characters")
        .doc("Trillian");

    // init crew members of the Heart of Gold
    await heartOfGold.set({
        crew: [],
        crewCount: 0,
    });

    // save the character Trillian to the DB
    const trillianData = { name: "Trillian", inSpace: false };
    await trillianRef.set(trillianData);

    // wait until the CF is done.
    await snooz();

    // check if the crew size has change
    const heart = await heartOfGold.get();
    const trillian = await trillianRef.get();

    console.log("heart", heart.data());
    console.log("trillian", trillian.data());

    // at this point the Heart of Gold has one crew member and trillian is in space
    assert.deepStrictEqual(heart.data().crewCount, 1, "Crew Members");
    assert.deepStrictEqual(trillian.data().inSpace, true, "In Space");
});
```

### run the test

To run the tests and emulator in one go, we navigate into the `functions` folder and write `yarn firebase emulators:exec "yarn test --exit"`. This command can also be used in your CI pipeline. Or you can use `npm test` instead.

If it all worked, you should see the following output

```
  √ Add Crew Members (5413ms)

  1 passing (8S)
```

Comment: When do you `initializeApp` then? It's not clear from your example. I would expect it to run inside index.js. Can you clarify?

Comment: Last week, I went to the Firebase Summit in Madrid to talk to the Firebase Team. They told be how to correctly setup the test suit. I have updated the code above accordingly.

Comment: You can also find a codelab here: https://google.dev/playlists/firebase-emulators Point 5 `Test Drive Complex Firebase Functions` is of interest for you

Comment: Why do you use `this.timeout(0);`?

Comment: Because the default timeout of mocha is so short, you can not even start the emulators, etc. before it fails. In my case I simply deactivated the timeout. In production you can set it to something more realistic. For example 10seconds or so.

Comment: Great summary. Is there a way to test other functions in the index.js file directly? I have some helper functions that I would like to test directly instead of as a result of triggers.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone struggling with testing firestore triggers, I've made an example repository that will hopefully help other people.

https://github.com/benwinding/example-jest-firestore-triggers

It uses jest and the local firebase emulator.

Comment: hi Ben, could you please help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66964566/how-to-properly-initialize-firebase-functions-test-using-cloud-function ?I am struggling testing firestore triggers using emulator. maybe you can help

Comment: Sure @sarah I'll try