# how to properly initialize firebase functions test using cloud function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using

- Node 14
- firebase-functions-test: 0.2.3
- firebase-admin: 9.6.0
- firebase-functions: 3.13.2
- firebase tools: 9.8.0

so I want to perform unit testing for my firestore trigger function using firebase cloud function, I read the steps from [the documentation in here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing).

I want to perform unit test using `Firebase Emulator`. so I assume I will initialize the SDK in offline mode. [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#offline-mode) said that

> If you would like to write completely offline tests, you can
> initialize the SDK without any parameters:

so I initialize it like this

```
import * as firebase from "firebase-functions-test";

const test = firebase();
const wrapped = test.wrap(myFunctions.onCreate);

// rest of my test code
```

but when I run the test, I have this error:

> Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to
> https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more
> information.

so even though I will use Firebase emulator (offline), it seems I need to provide the credential, which is the step if online mode is used, like explained from [documentation in here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#online-mode)

so I initialize the SDK like this

```
import * as firebase from "firebase-functions-test";

const test = firebase({
    databaseURL: "https://xxx-b843e.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "xxx-b843e",
}, "../../../service-account.json");

const wrapped = test.wrap(myFunctions.onCreate);

// rest of my test code
```

but when I run the test, I have another error

> {"severity":"WARNING","message":"Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG and
> GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variables are missing. Initializing
> firebase-admin will fail"}
>
> Error: The file at ../../../service-account.json does not exist, or it
> is not a file. ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat
> '/Users/xxx/Documents/service-account.json'

the service account json file doesn't exist? I believe I have set the path correctly like this

[image]

in fact, I use intellisense to guide me to service-account.json path
[image]

the service-account.json file is like the image below, i get it from firebase project overview --> project settings --> service accounts --> generate new private key

[image]

what should I do if I want to initialize firebase functions test SDK in Firebase emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation

```
Error: The file at ../../../service-account.json does not exist
```

That error means that the `service-account.json` file could not be found at runtime (when you started the emulator), because the relative path is incorrect.

> in fact, I use intellisense to guide me to service-account.json path

The path that *intellisense* suggests may not be the correct *relative* to the directory the code is executing in. This is because typescript is compiled before it's run, usually from within a `lib` or `dist` folder, which means the relative path needs to be changed.

#### Solution 1

You can use an absolute path `/my/absolutepath/to/service-account.json`, this is a fast way to resolve this problem, but isn't very portable.

#### Solution 2

Experiment with different amounts of `../../` to find the exact ***relative*** path of the `service-account.json`. Try using:

- `../../service-account.json`
- `../../../service-account.json`
- etc ... (until it works)

It's most likely only off by a few `../`

Comment: thanks Ben. I can solve it using  `./service-account.json` it really make me confused . maybe I need to learn more about relative and absolute path first

Answer (score 0):

To use the offline mode you need to stub API calls like `admin.initializeApp()`. See the  example given at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#importing_your_functions

```js
// If index.js calls admin.initializeApp at the top of the file,
// we need to stub it out before requiring index.js. This is because the
// functions will be executed as a part of the require process.
// Here we stub admin.initializeApp to be a dummy function that doesn't do anything.
adminInitStub = sinon.stub(admin, 'initializeApp');
// Now we can require index.js and save the exports inside a namespace called myFunctions.
myFunctions = require('../index');
```

To test against the emulator you need to the initialize the test SDK with an emulator URL. Your file not found error is probably due to a problem with resolving relative paths. Try providing an absolute path and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the warning should be as simple as adding the following to your `jest.preset.js` (or whatever code runs before your unit tests run).

```js
const test = require('firebase-functions-test')();
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#offline-mode