# Is it possible to assert the number of reads/writes in a Firebase Cloud Function test?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a test suite that runs integration tests for my Firebase Cloud Functions against a locally running Firebase emulator, is it possible to assert the number of reads/writes made to the emulated Firestore instance?

E.g. for the following function I would want to assert that 1 write occurs & 0 reads

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const original = data.query.text;
    const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection("/messages").add({ original: original });
    return { code: 200, message: "Success" };
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup a firebase firestore and cloud function test suit with firebase Emulator for JS development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56236348/how-to-setup-a-firebase-firestore-and-cloud-function-test-suit-with-firebase-emu)

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB Nope! I already have my test suite up & running. What I want is to be able to assert during a test that exactly X reads & Y writes occured in the emulated Firestore

Comment: @MichaelMcCormick Feel free to give any feedback to the answer. Let us know if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Its not possible to assert the number of reads and writes in a Firebase Cloud Function test.

I would suggest that the best way would be is to write the test data to the [**Firebase Emulator**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite), then read it back and also count the number of collections/documents as well using [**Client SDK**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/client/libraries).

If you want to assert data coming from the Firebase Emulator, then you can use Requests Monitor. We used Client SDK for this purpose as Admin SDK requests and access  calls will not be listed because it bypass Security Rules. It's a current limitation according to this [Blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2021/08/firestore-emulator-requests-monitor.html).

The Firebase emulator has a log that shows requests as shown in example below.
[image: Firebase Emulator Suite]

*Note: I don't think that you should have a dependency on it, since [Firebase Emulator Request Monitor](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2021/08/firestore-emulator-requests-monitor.html) is a new feature that its implementation may change and Admin SDK can be included over time.*